linker command failed with exit code 1 and Undefined symbols xcode 15
I have added the pod 'AGConnectCore'.
While building an application, I am getting this issue:

d: Undefined symbols:
OBJC_CLASS$_AGCAccessNetworkStatus, referenced from:
in AGConnectCore[arm64]9
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)


Tried with solution using pod deinit and added again.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/68217994/833395 please check

Undefined Symbols in Linking iOS App - https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/729712?answerId=756717022#756717022 also look
